# How to get a value from JSON

Tags: python, json

This is the first time I'm working with JSON, and I'm trying to pull `url` out of the JSON below.

```
{
    "name": "The_New11d112a_Company_Name",
    "sections": [
        {
            "name": "Products",
            "payload": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "TERi Geriatric Patient Skills Trainer,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Contact Info",
            "payload": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "contacts",
                    "url": "https://www.a3bs.com/catheterization-kits-8000892-3011958-3b-scientific,p_1057_31043.html",
                    "contacts": [
                        {
                        "name": "User",
                        "email": "Company Email",
                        "phone": "Company PhoneNumber"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "contact"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"tags": [
    "Male",
    "Airway"
],
"_id": "0e4cd5c6-4d2f-48b9-acf2-5aa75ade36e1"
```

}

I have been able to access `description` and `_id` via

```
data = json.loads(line)
        if 'xpath' in data:
            xpath = data["_id"]
            description = data["sections"][0]["payload"][0]["description"]
```

However, I can't seem to figure out a way to access `url`. One other issue I have is there could be other items in `sections`, which makes indexing into `Contact Info` a non starter.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
import json

with open("test.json", "r") as f:
    json_out = json.load(f)
    for i in json_out["sections"]:
        for j in i["payload"]:
            for key in j:
                if "url" in key:
                    print(key, '->', j[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your JSON is damaged, it should be like that.

```json
{
    "name": "The_New11d112a_Company_Name",
    "sections": [
        {
            "name": "Products",
            "payload": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "TERi Geriatric Patient Skills Trainer",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Contact Info",
            "payload": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "contacts",
                    "url": "https://www.a3bs.com/catheterization-kits-8000892-3011958-3b-scientific,p_1057_31043.html",
                    "contacts": [
                        {
                        "name": "User",
                        "email": "Company Email",
                        "phone": "Company PhoneNumber"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "contact"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"tags": [
    "Male",
    "Airway"
],
"_id": "0e4cd5c6-4d2f-48b9-acf2-5aa75ade36e1"
}
```

You can check it on http://json.parser.online.fr/.

And if you want to get the value of the url.

```py
import json
j = json.load(open('yourJSONfile.json'))
print(j['sections'][1]['payload'][0]['url'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth to write a short function to get the `url(s)` and make a decision whether or not to use the first found `url` in the returned list, or skip processing if there's no url available in your data.

The method shall looks like this:

```
def extract_urls(data):
    payloads = []
    for section in data['sections']:
        payloads += section.get('payload') or []

    urls = [x['url'] for x in payloads if 'url' in x]

    return urls
```

Answer (score 1):

This should print out the URL

```
import json
# open json file to read
with open('test.json','r') as f:
    # load json, parameter as json text (file contents)
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    # after observing format of JSON data, the location of the URL key
    # is determined and the data variable is manipulated to extract the value
    print(data['sections'][1]['payload'][0]['url'])
```

The exact location of the 'url' key:

1st (position) of the array which is the value of the key 'sections'

Inside the array value, there is a dict, and the key 'payload' contains an array

In the 0th (position) of the array is a dict with a key 'url'

---

While testing my solution, I noticed that the json provided is flawed, after fixing the json flaws(3), I ended up with this.

```
{
"name": "The_New11d112a_Company_Name",
"sections": [
    {
        "name": "Products",
        "payload": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "TERi Geriatric Patient Skills Trainer",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Contact Info",
        "payload": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "contacts",
                "url": "https://www.a3bs.com/catheterization-kits-8000892-3011958-3b-scientific,p_1057_31043.html",
                "contacts": [
                    {
                    "name": "User",
                    "email": "Company Email",
                    "phone": "Company PhoneNumber"
                }
            ],
            "type": "contact"
        }
    ]
}
],
"tags": [
"Male",
"Airway"
],
"_id": "0e4cd5c6-4d2f-48b9-acf2-5aa75ade36e1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

After utilizing the JSON that was provided by Vincent55.
I made a working code with exception handling and with certain assumptions.

Working Code:

```
## Assuming that the target data is always under sections[i].payload
from json import loads
line = open("data.json").read()
data = loads(line)["sections"]
for x in data:
    try:
        # With assumption that there is only one payload
        if x["payload"][0]["url"]:
            print(x["payload"][0]["url"])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```